# Why does sed behave differently in a shell script?

Tags: shell, sed

Why does sed behave differently depending upon whether it's run from the command line or a shell script?  Here's a basic example:

```
$ cat test.txt
foo
bar
baz

$ sed -e 's/^b\(\w*\)$/q\1/g' test.txt # works as intended
foo
qar
qaz

$ cat test.sh # The exact same command
sed -e 's/^b\(\w*\)$/q\1/g' test.txt

$ bash test.sh
foo
bar
baz
```

Now, as I look into this further, `\w` isn't a standard BRE or ERE (even with the `-E` flag) character class in POSIX regexes.  It's these sorts of Perl-like GNU extensions to REs that don't work when I run the command from a shell script. Indeed, if I change `\w` to the POSIX `[[:alnum:]]` it works as I intend. No GNU extensions seem to work from the shell script (including uppercase/lowercase `\U` and `\L`). So does `sed` try to detect if it's running from a shell script and enter some sort of strict POSIX-only mode?  Is there documentation about this?  Can I disable this behavior?

(This is `gsed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`)

Comment: cannot reproduce. Using MSYS Windows 10 & sed 4.2.2 & your test data. I get the proper result from command line or shell.

Comment: Ooooh, I found the discrepancy.  A long time ago I had aliased `sed` to `gsed` in my `~/.bash_profile`.  I had previously verified `which sed`, but I didn't double-check `type sed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was simply that I had a long-forgotten bash alias changing `sed` to `gsed` — the GNU version as installed by Homebrew.  That explains why `sed --version` reported itself as `gsed` at the command line.  I had checked `which sed` from both the script and the prompt, but I didn't think about `type` and bash aliases.

```
$ type sed
sed is aliased to `gsed'
```

Comment: I had the same issue and forgot about the aliases! Thank you!