# cygwin sed Command behaves differently in script vs in-line

Tags: bash, shell, sed, cygwin

I am currently running sed with variable line input to remove a set number of lines from a file.

```
sed -i '1,'$SomeVariable'd' somefile.extention
```

Now, this works as intended if I enter it in cygwin. However, if I run it via a shell script, it does not delete the lines as intended. It still picks up their contents, but does not delete them afterwards.

While looking for a solution, I came across [Why does sed behave differently in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183218/why-does-sed-behave-differently-in-a-shell-script?rq=1)

This does not answer my question as I have verified that bash is running sed and not gsed.

Comment: What do you mean by "It still picks up their contents, but does not delete them afterwards"? The only thing this does is delete them. "afterwards" -- after what?

Comment: I upvoted the question you linked to because it has a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) complete with a transcript, input files, script file, invocation, plus expected and actual output. It made it really easy to see exactly how the problem manifested itself, and allowed me to try it on my machine without having to guess what the variables or files contained. It would be great if you did the same so I could upvote yours too.

Comment: Since you are not using regular expressions, `sed` vs. `gsed` is moot here. Are you sure `$SomeVariable` has the expected value? It looks like it has a value of `0`... If you rely on the value it has in the invoking shell, you should `export` it before invoking your script...

Comment: Also, quote your variables: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: I'd strongly suggest running your script with `bash -x yourscript` to log the commands it runs.

Comment: @Erudaki, ...should you do so, consider [edit]ing that log into the question (if the log doesn't answer the question in and of itself). Building a [mcve] allowing others to reproduce the issue would be even better.